# Google Places API: INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: react-native, google-places-api, google-places

Hi I'm trying to use the google places API but I keep getting a status of INVALID_REQUEST my url looks like this and below is my code.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-122.449833,37.479942&radius=10000&key=MY_API_KEY

```
const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?' + 'location=' + region.longitude + ',' + region.latitude + '&radius=10000' + '&key=' + API_KEY;

// console.log(url)
// axios.get(url).then((response) => {
//     console.log(response)
// }).catch((err) => {
//     console.log(err)
// })

fetch(url).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.json())
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: The radius in the URL should be 100 not 10000